# Migrating massive databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, database-migration

One of the tasks in a project that I'm working on is to migrate an existing database on SQL Server 2000, to a new server which runs SQL Server 2008. This database is extremely huge, with 23 million rows and a 78GB mdf file.

What is the best way to migrate a database of this size?

My current approach would be to:

- allow for application downtime so that the application doesn't write records to the database
- perform a full backup on SQL Server 2000.
- move backup file over to new server across the network.
- restore full backup on SQL Server 2008.
- configure the application to refer to the database on the new server
- restart application.
- decommission the database on SQL Server 2000.

However, I'm not sure how much application downtime that would involve.

Are there any easier approaches, or an approach that involves very little downtime? Can a backup be taken while the application is running? Obviously I would need to stop the application when the backup file is transferred and the restore is completed. Interested to hear your approaches to a task like this.

Comment: You can test the expected downtime using some existing backup. Also you should test your migration before doing it live. Also worth a read: http://thomaslarock.com/2011/12/7-mistakes-you-cant-afford-to-make-when-upgrading-to-sql-2012/ (7 Mistakes You Can’t Afford To Make When Upgrading to SQL 2012) Applies to any migration.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to downtime:

- Detach the database
- Copy data file(s) and log file(s) to the new server
- Attach the database on the new server instance

Detaching closes the database and finalizes the files so they safely can be moved (or backed up via filesystem backup).  It will no longer be accessible on the server instance until you reattach it.

Don't cut and paste / move the data and log files, just in case something bombs during the copy.

There are several other things to keep in mind when migrating to a new server instance, like making sure logins exist on the new instance, features in use that might be deprecated, etc.

Here's the reference for [**detach/attach**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx).

Comment: BTW- 78 GB isn't really that massive.  Large, yes.  Massive - not in the industry context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the sound of detaching the database as it sounds to me that that would preclude the need for taking a full backup and restore.

Comment: BTW- 78 GB isn't really that massive. Large, yes. Massive - not in the industry context. > all relative isn't it ;-).

Comment: @acha114 Yep, totally relative :)  I thought I had big db's with 750GB, then talked to others who put me in my place with 20+ TB db's.

Comment: well, you've put me in my place too! ;-)

Comment: @acha114 Doh! Haha, yeah was definitely not meaning it that way!

Comment: @acha114 - I would still do the full backup and log backups leading up to before the detach. Better safe than sorry. You could always time your migration to coincide with existing backup schedules if need be.

Comment: @Kevin Agreed.  I always assume a full backup before any migration but it's certainly worth having out there on the table.